# Extract all IP address from text file and fill array

Tags: ruby, regex, ip

I have a text file with IP addresses and other data that is similar to this below:

```
name  8.8.8.8  1    1   200,940 ***
company  139.130.4.5  1 1   365,550 ***
```

I am trying to get the IP addresses and add to an array. I believe the regex I need is

```
r'(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})'
```

but how can I read through and find each occurrence? I also read about IPAdr but that seems to be used for manipulating/checking IP addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = []
File.new("/path_to_file")
.each_line{|s| a << s[/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/]}
a # => ["8.8.8.8", "139.130.4.5"]
```

Comment: thanks alot but could you explain to me what this bit is doing     .each_line{|s| a << s

Comment: It is adding the matched substring to an array.

Comment: I gather that. What I mean is how does it work       |s| a <<   is the s the substring?

Comment: The iterator `each_line` passes a line from the content of the file to `s` per iteration.

Comment: ahh so thats how it works |s| is each line and |a| is placing it into the array. Ok awesome thanks heaps for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more readable version of the code:

```
text = File.open('/path_to_file').read
ips = text.scan(/\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/m)
ips # => ["8.8.8.8", "139.130.4.5"]
```